# Organisations in Resident Evil Universe

Tags: video-games, zombie, resident-evil

Is it possible to be part of more than one anti-bioterrorism organization [BSA,D.S.O,TerraSave]? And is there a in universe example?

Comment: This looks a lot like you asked the same question twice.

Comment: Not the same the other question is what is the difference this one is about membership in orginization